# How can I add an error message in my `TextFormField` like error messages in java?

Tags: android, flutter, dart, android-edittext

I wanna have something like these errors in flutter `TextFormField`:

[image]

Comment: You mean you want to add validation to TextFields or you want the design to look like that?

Comment: @BilaalAbdelHassan
I did the validation. I want the error messages to appear like this

Comment: a [Tooltip](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Tooltip-class.html)?

Comment: @pskink No. a tooltip is useful when we have for example an `IconButton` and we're ganna add a label to it so that when a user holds the `IconButtn`, its label is shown. also a `TextFormField` doesn't have tooltip property.  
I want the `TextFormField`'s error messages to appear as they do in an android application written in java or kotlin!

Comment: then grab `Tooltip` source code and create a custom widget that appears when you need it showing your error message (most likely `Tooltip` uses `Overlay` class)

Comment: @pskink I want the error messages to act exactly like android `EditText` error messages. not like a tooltip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should attach an `Overlay` to your `TextFormField`. see this [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/flutter-implementing-overlay/)