# what is the best way of generating dynamic graphql queries in dart?

Tags: flutter, graphql

I wrote this method in dart to dynamically generate a graphql query and it works as expected:

```
String getPosts({
  bool id = false,
  bool title = false,
  bool description = false,
  bool date = false,
  bool creator = false,
}) {
  final fieldsStringList = [
    if (id) "_id",
    if (title) "title",
    if (description) "description",
    if (date) "date",
    if (creator) "creator{_id}",
  ];

  String fieldsString = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < fieldsStringList.length; i++) {
    fieldsString += fieldsStringList[i];
    if (i != fieldsStringList.length - 1) fieldsString += ',';
  }

  return 'query{posts{$fieldsString}}';
}
```

But I wanna know if there is a better way of doing that?

Comment: see `List.join()` method

Comment: did you try `List.join()`? it simply returns a `String` of joined elements

Comment: @pskink wow thank you. I tryed fieldsStringList.join(',') and it worked as I wanted. I think that was the best way

Comment: you can use a `Map` too: `void main() {
bool date = true;
bool id = false;
bool title = true;

var all = {'date': date, 'id': id, 'title': title};
  
var o = all.keys.where((k) => all[k]).join(',');
print('filtered: $o');
}`

Comment: yeah that works too. I think there might not be so much difference between using a map and using a list! and I think using a list like I did is more readable

Comment: @pskink I really appreciate you for your attention.
please let me know if you have any idea about my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62348145/how-can-i-add-an-error-message-in-my-textformfield-like-error-messages-in-java?noredirect=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for others who have the same situation, thanks to @pskink this is a really better way of achieving that:

```
String getPosts({
  bool id = false,
  bool title = false,
  bool description = false,
  bool date = false,
  bool creator = false,
}) {
  final fields = [
    if (id) "_id",
    if (title) "title",
    if (description) "description",
    if (date) "date",
    if (creator) "creator{_id}",
  ];

  if (fields.isEmpty)
    throw EmptyQueryException('getPost() query must have at least 1 argument');

  return 'query{posts{${fields.join(',')}}}';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `StringBuffer` instead of `String`, and use `for each` loop instead of regular.

```
String getPosts({
  bool id = false,
  bool title = false,
  bool description = false,
  bool date = false,
  bool creator = false,
}) {
  final stringsList = <String>[
    if (id) '_id',
    if (title) 'title',
    if (description) 'description',
    if (date) 'date',
    if (creator) 'creator{_id}',
  ];

  final buffer = StringBuffer();

  for (var item in stringsList) {
    buffer.write(item);
    if (stringsList.last != item) buffer.write(',');
  }

  return 'query{posts{$buffer}}';
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response.
yeah that's better. but I wanna know if there is a way not to use a list and a for loop!